# how to check for duplicate entries and retain an entry during movement using angular13

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi am using angular13 in my application. in the given demo, i am able to move the items completely from left to right and vice versa, so duplicate records are avoided, but here now,

1. i must move the records from left to right and must keep a copy of that in left also.
2. if i click on right item to move to left, both the items ae getting selected, i mean in both left side and right side, i want the item to be selected in which side i choose that item.

3.above 2 items are fixed, but now the issue is that, I choose few items to move from left to right, when clicked on button, the list is still having active class.

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingBasicAgentsGroupView">
    <a
      href="javascript:void(0);"
      class="d-block h5 mb-0"
      data-target="#basicAgentsGroupView"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="basicAgentsGroupView"
      >Group View</a
    >
  </div>
  <div
    class=""
    id="basicAgentsGroupView"
    aria-labelledby="headingBasicAgentsGroupView"
    data-parent="#basicTabAccordion"
  >
    <div class="card-body" id="agents-group-view">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Group</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Not in Group</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 swap-list list-left">
            <div class="card-header border-bottom-0 rounded-top">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="SearchDualList"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Search"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body overflow-auto py-0">
              <ul
                class="list-group list-group-flush"
                *ngFor="let child of agentInView"
                name="agentInGroup"
              >
                <li
                  class="list-group-item {{
                    isInActiveItems(child) ? 'active' : ''
                  }}"
                  (click)="toggleActiveItem(child)"
                >
                  {{ child.value }}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="col-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center list-arrows"
        >
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-outline-primary my-3 move-right"
            (click)="moveToTheRight()"
          >
            Move Right
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-outline-primary my-3 move-left"
            (click)="moveToTheLeft()"
          >
            Move Left
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 swap-list list-right">
            <div class="card-header border-bottom-0 rounded-top">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Search"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body overflow-auto py-0">
              <ul
                class="list-group list-group-flush"
                *ngFor="let child of agentNotinView"
                name="agentNotInGroup"
              >
                <li
                  class="list-group-item {{
                    isInActiveItems(child) ? 'active' : ''
                  }}"
                  (click)="toggleActiveItem(child)"
                >
                  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="child.value" />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  public moveToTheRight(): void {
    this.move('agentInView', 'agentNotinView');
  }

  public moveToTheLeft(): void {
    this.move('agentNotinView', 'dummyArray');
  }

  // moving function
  public move(from: string, to: string): void {
    this[from] = this[from].filter((item: any, i: number) => {
      if (this.isInActiveItems(item)) {
        this[to].push({...item});
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });

    // if needed
    // sort if needed
    this[to].sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1));

    // clean active items after action
    this.activeItems.length = 0;
  }

  public toggleActiveItem(eventItem: any): void {
    if (this.activeItems.find((item) => item === eventItem)) {
      this.activeItems = this.activeItems.filter((item) => item !== eventItem);
      this.agentInView.push(eventItem);
    } else {
      this.activeItems.push(eventItem);
    }
  }

  public isInActiveItems(eventItem: any): boolean {
    return !!this.activeItems.find((item) => item === eventItem);
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5enazb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: In your demo link, I can't get anything to move to the right.  Is it working for you?

Comment: It looks like your demo link needs to be updated.  Can you copy and paste the typescript code in your question to your demo?  I think your demo is an older version of the code

Comment: hi Jake, i have updated my demo, please check

Comment: @JakeSmith demo has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem with selection happening on both sides is because the objects in your array are being passed by reference, so the same instance of these objects are both on the left and right.  I would suggest that you make copies of the objects inside of the `move` method.

Comment: hi @Jake, that issue is fixed, but now my issue is that, once i select the items from left and try to move to right, it gets moved but active class has got still set to the left side objects, any idea how that can be fixed

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5enazb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts this is the demo link, i had updated in my question